# How many ways can you divide a group of people into boxes?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

**In how many ways can you divide $25$ people with the name A-Y into $5$ identical non-empty boxes if A is not allowed to end up in the same group as any of B, C or D?**

I used sterlings number but I am not sure if I am correct. Here is my solution

Total = $S(25,5)$
case $1$: ABCD are in the same group, which means we can count them as one, so we have $S(22,5)$
case $2$: A is in the same group as 2 so $S(23,5)* C(3,2)$
case $3$: A is with one so $S(24,5)* C(3,1)$
Answer= Total - (case $1$ + case $2$ + case $3$) =
Am I correct because my friend solved it in another way I don't understand and got a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

We do not want such cases : $\{A,B\}$ or $\{A,C\}$ or $\{A,D\}$ . Hence , we must subtract them from the total solution , as you said. However , the missing part in your solution is  to use Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion.

- The number of distribution of $25$ people into $5$ non-empty  identical boxes : $S(25,5)$ or $$\frac{25![x^{25}][ (e^x -1)^5]}{5!}$$
- The number of distribution of $25$ people into $5$ non-empty identical boxes when $A$ and $B$ are together : $$\frac{23![x^{23}][e^x (e^x -1)^4]}{4!}$$
- The number of distribution of $25$ people into $5$ non-empty identical boxes when $A$ and $C$ are together : $$\frac{23![x^{23}][e^x (e^x -1)^4]}{4!}$$
- The number of distribution of $25$ people into $5$ non-empty identical boxes when $A$ and $D$ are together : $$\frac{23![x^{23}][e^x (e^x -1)^4]}{4!}$$
- The number of distribution of $25$ people into $5$ non-empty identical boxes when $A$ ,$B$ ,$C$ are together : $$\frac{22![x^{22}][e^x (e^x -1)^4]}{4!}$$
- The number of distribution of $25$ people into $5$ non-empty identical boxes when $A$ ,$B$ ,$D$ are together : $$\frac{22![x^{22}][e^x (e^x -1)^4]}{4!}$$
- The number of distribution of $25$ people into $5$ non-empty identical boxes when $A$ ,$C$ ,$D$ are together : $$\frac{22![x^{22}][e^x (e^x -1)^4]}{4!}$$
- The number of distribution of $25$ people into $5$ non-empty identical boxes when $A$ ,$B$ ,$C$ ,$D$ are together : $$\frac{21![x^{21}][e^x (e^x -1)^4]}{4!}$$

**By P.I.E:**  $$\frac{25![x^{25}][e^x (e^x -1)^4]}{4!}- 3\bigg(\frac{23![x^{23}][e^x (e^x -1)^4]}{4!}\bigg)+3\bigg(\frac{22![x^{22}][e^x (e^x -1)^4]}{4!}\bigg)-\bigg(\frac{21![x^{21}][e^x (e^x -1)^4]}{4!}\bigg)$$

Comment: Sorry but I have never seen this way of rewriting S(25, 5) as 25![x25][(ex−1)5]/5! I thought sterling only had a recursive formula but anyways would you mind explaining that tho?

Comment: @First_1st the form is called generating function (actually it is exponential generating function ). It is so wide topic to talk here

Comment: but did you do the same thing as me but instead you used this formula? Or what is it i did wrong if we look at my solution.

Comment: I believe that (1) it can easily be solved without PIE, (2) if PIE is to be used, the denominator in your expressions should remain 5!

Comment: @trueblueanil $5!$ is wrong in denominator , because we made them identical boxes but there are two types of dstribution in numerator $e^x$ and $(e^x -1)$ , so it is $4!$. Actually they are $4! \times 1!$